# Ext 4.2 hasOne association foreignKey

Tags: extjs4

I have two models with a hasOne association.

But, when I try to get the associated model using the getter method (extdirect), the foreignKey isn't automatic populated.

Should I expect that?

The hasMany association seems to be working well (I have the foreignKey automatic set by the framework).

Comment: Please provide your Model definitions so that we may more clearly understand and troubleshoot your issue... An example response from your configured proxy would also be very helpful.

Comment: Copypaste some of your code for us